# how to move the tick and label position of the secondary x and y axes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple axes using matplotlib in python. I have done it using twinx().twin(y) but I am not able to move the tick postion and the axis label with the spines of the new axes.please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.itervalues():
        sp.set_visible(False)
def MultiAxes(*xy):
        fig, host=plt.subplots()
        fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

        new=xy[0]

        x=new[0]
        y=new[1]
        x1=new[2]
        y1=new[3]
        x2=new[4]
        y2=new[5]

        new_Axes=host.twinx().twiny()

        p1,= host.plot(x,y,"b-",label="X0-Y0 plot")

        p2,= host.plot(x1,y1,"r-",label="X1-Y1 Plot")

        host.set_xlim(0,20)
        host.set_ylim(0,30)

        host.set_xlabel("X0 Axis")
        host.set_ylabel("Y0 Axis")

        make_patch_spines_invisible(new_Axes)

        new_Axes.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 10))
        new_Axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        new_Axes.spines['left'].set_visible(True)

        new_Axes.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 10))
        new_Axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        new_Axes.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)

        new_Axes.set_xlim(0,30)
        new_Axes.set_ylim(0,40)
        new_Axes.set_xlabel("X1 Axis")
        new_Axes.set_ylabel("Y1 Axis")

        p3,= new_Axes.plot(x2,y2,"g--",label="X2-Y2 Plot")

        lines = [p1, p2, p3]

        host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines],loc="upper left")


        plt.show()

x=[2,4,6,8,9,10,12,15]
y=[0,3,5,6,8,9,10,15]
x1=[0,3,5,7,9,13,15,17]
y1=[1,4,5,8,11,15,17,19]
x2=[0,2,4,5,17,18,19,30]
y2=[0,2,4,5,17,18,19,30]
val=[x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2]
MultiAxes(val)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not able to move the tick positions and axis labels? Currently you did not add any labels for the secondary axis. And where do you want to place them? And where do you want the tick positions?